# Python:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, html, parsing, split, beautifulsoup

```
 h = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "products"})
for row in h:
    b = row.findAll("div", {"class": "gd-row"})
    for a in b:
        c = a.findAll("div", {"class": "gd-col"})
        for d in c:
            e = d.findAll("div", {"class": "product-unit"})
            for f in e:
                g = f.findAll("div", {"class": "pu-details"})
                for h in g:
                    i = h.findAll("div", {"class": "pu-title"})
                    for k in i:
                        l = k.findAll('a')
                        for z in l:
                            text = z.get('href')

                            title = str(z.get_text().strip())
                            urldict.update({counter: text})
                            print (str(counter) + ')' + title)

                            titlelist.append(title)

                            counter = counter + 1


print ("\nSeems we found more than one same mobile type, help us by selecting appropiate model \n")
user_choice = input("\nEnter your choice (number) which matches exactly:")
url_from_search = "http://www.xyzabc.com{}".format(
    urldict.get(user_choice).split('&')[0])
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am trying to do html parsing with the help of beautifulsoup.The code given above is throwing attribute error. What might be the issue? Kindly help me if possible.

Comment: When you post an error, it is preferable to post the stack trace or at least the error where the error occurred. Python gives you the stack trace to help debug, ... so pass it along!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, `user_choice` key is not inside the `urldict` dictionary and `urldict.get(user_choice)` returns `None`. Assuming you are using Python 3 and your `urldict` keys are integers, you need to convert the input number to integer before making a lookup:

```
user_choice = int(input("\nEnter your choice (number) which matches exactly:"))
url_from_search = "http://www.acxcs.com{}".format(
    urldict.get(user_choice).split('&')[0])
```

Also, you should probably handle the "missing key" situation better. For example:

```
user_choice = int(input("\nEnter your choice (number) which matches exactly:"))
if user_choice not in urldict:
    print("Error, the number is not valid")
else:
    url_from_search = "http://www.acxcs.com{}".format(urldict[user_choice].split('&')[0])
```